# pdb remote debugging over socket for Sublime Text 2 plug-in development

Tags: python, sublimetext2, pdb

I'd like to put Python pdb statements in Sublime Text 2 plug-in code. The problem is that this code is run in an embedded Python which does not provide the required console access (stdin, stdout) to make pdb functional.

Are there any Python pdb implementations which would work over a socket connection or similar methods. The plugin code would open a socket for listening and with a "pdb client" one could connect to this port.

Then, when pdb breakpoint is encountered the pdb client terminal would be used for the interaction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384626/how-to-debug-sublime-plugins-during-development?noredirect=1#comment23483174_16384626

This answer solve your issue with remote debugging