# Run Python Debugger (pdb) in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, breakpoints, sublime-text-plugin, sublimerepl

How can you set python debugger ([pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)) breakpoints in Sublime Text 3?

Both [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) or [Python Breakpoints](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Breakpoints) fail with default python build system:

```
print "hello"
# code runs fine without this breakpoint
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
print "bye"

>>>File "C:\Python27\lib\bdb.py", line 49, in trace_dispatch
>>>return self.dispatch_line(frame)
    >>>File "C:\Python27\lib\bdb.py", line 68, in dispatch_line
    >>>if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
```

Above issue appears [documented](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9027), but with no obvious fix. Or has the answer been staring at me?

Comment: See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16385039/4131059

It doesn't fix the `stdin` issue, but it does fix `stdout`. Of course, since for the REPLs, `stdin` is already defined, this skirts the issue nicely.

Comment: Have you tried the plugin at [github.com/obormot/PythonBreakpoints](https://github.com/obormot/PythonBreakpoints)?

Comment: Why don't you use eclipse or pycharm which even include remote debugging?
Eclipse with pydev will even allow you to inject code while running. Is there a reason that these options cannot be considered?

Comment: Have you tried pointing the Python27 executable to the vanilla file? Does the same stack trace come back?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to deal with additional packages, you can create a snippet to set the breakpoint for you.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[import pdb;pdb.set_trace()]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>pdb</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.python</scope>
    <description>Insert a breakpoint</description>
</snippet>
```

The above snippet will trigger whenever you type `pdb` in your code.[image: autocomplete window when the snippet is triggered]

**Instructions On a Mac**

- Navigate to Tools -> Developer -> New Snippet
- Replace the template with the snippet above
- Save the snippet to ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User
- Ensure the name ends with sublime-snippet (ex. breakpoint.sublime-snippet)

It should start working immediately after saving.

---------- UPDATE 29 NOV 2019 ----------

As mentioned by @FamousSnake in the comments below, you can modify the snippet to use the built-in [breakpoint()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) function if you're using Python 3.7 or higher. This is especially convenient if you use linters or utilities like black to format your code. It should get them to stop complaining or splitting the code above into multiple lines. You can use the revised snippet below:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[breakpoint()]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>pdb</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.python</scope>
    <description>Insert a breakpoint</description>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Since python 3.7 you can use built-in breakpoint() function that will do exactly the same - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/

Answer (score 4):

python breakpoint plugin and check this link [python breakpoint debugger](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Breakpoints)

**Use ctrl+shift+b to toggle breakpoint in a line**

But its not preferable solution for  debugging a software using a text editor.
There are best IDE which makes your development lot easier

- visual studio community edition
- Pycharm
- Eclipse
- Komodo

Comment: you've referenced the same sublime tool that I based my question on.

Comment: The existence of IDE's is well known, but much as some people still prefer to use VIM, some people also prefer the light weight and still  somewhat powerful sublime text.  Having opinions isn't especially relevant to his question.

Answer (score -3):

You could try to use an IDE specific for Python which makes debugging and setting up python projects really easy.  I would recommend you try the free community version of Pycharm.

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/

Comment: trincot - Naturally, I will have to disagree with you.  Why use a dull axe when what you actually need is a pair of sharp scissors when cutting some paper, for instance?   The solution is to use an editor that makes python development super easy, so that you do not have the breakpoint issue in the first place.  Choosing the right tool for the job is the solution here,  Furthermore, Pycharm community edition is FREE, so what is wrong with promoting a free product, which is super solid?  @Raja seems to agree.

Comment: This is not an answer; it's a comment.